# Upload Hosted in-app Purchase Content Xcode 7

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, xcode7, iap-hosted-content

My understanding is that with Xcode 6 you could not upload a package of hosted content from within Xcode.  So, you had to use this application loader program, which I have downloaded.

But I now have upgraded to Xcode 7 and was expecting the bug to have been fixed.  My question is, "Is there any way to upload hosted content from within Xcode 7, or is it still necessary to use Application Loader?"

I ask, because at this point, when I attempt to upload the content I get:

**Archive validation failed due to the issues listed below.
An error occurred.
Archive item is not associated with any known iTunes Connect platform.**

Thanks for any further information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is that you must use the Application Loader.  I could never get around this problem after spending some time with it.  You would think they would have fixed it but no.

Still, it is not that difficult to use the App Loader and it does work well.